# How to develop backup strategy of many databases in 1 server

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, postgresql-12

I have a server with many databases...it contains like 20 databases. Some of them has 16 millions of rows, but not that many. There are usually very low to no activity at night but not that busy during day (except if there is an event, like new registration or member update). Although not busy, the databases contain critical data. None of the databases have been backed up for over a year !

How can I back them safely without crashing the server ? What do I need as early requirement ?
I have read many backup strategies but I am just overly cautious as I don't want to do silly stuff. I want to develop the safest backup method and "easily" recoverable.

At the moment, I have activated archiving and its already working nicely.

Any advice welcome or maybe there are articles that I should read.

My environment : Postgres 12 running on Ubuntu 20

Thanks

Comment: Run `pg_dumpall` to create a cluster dump as a quick measure. Then configure online file system backup, perhaps using pgBackRest.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, how do I handle and possibly avoid any spike in load ? the database can be really huge. It said here **"With massive databases, dumping with compression can be a time taking process. PostgreSQL rids you of this concern, too, as it allows you to dump several files in parallel. You can use the -j flag to do the same"** from [link] (https://arctype.com/blog/backup-postgres-database)  [link]

Comment: Sure that will cost you some. What do you expect? Don't compress the backup if speed and performance are a concern. It is more important to have a valid backup than to have good performance. Consider using `pg_basebackup --max-rate=...`.

Comment: thanks @LaurenzAlbe. What I am really afraid of is that this backup process will eat up lots of RAM and other resources I haven't thought about and eventually leads to a crash. I just can't afford that. Any other considerations I should take as precaution measures?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe. I have to avoid any surprise errors. Just like last time when  I changed the `max_wal_size` < `segment_size` without knowing that it is "forbidden". That caused DB can't start because of the failure of creating the "s.PG.5432" file.

Comment: Don't worry. A backup may cause some load, but it won't bring your server down.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thanks.. this really makes me confident.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having a backup at all, will cause much more frustration, when the database is corrupt, broken or becomes otherwise unavailable.

It's quite a simple calculation:

#### No backup

- out of business
- management unhappy
- customers unsatisfied
- great performance

#### Backup

- Slight degradation of performance during backup
- business continues
- management happy
- customers happy

#### pg_basebackup

Following is an excerpt from the `pg_basebackup` tool, that is shipped with PostgreSQL:

<sub>(**emphasis** mine)</sub>

> `pg_basebackup` is used to take base backups of a running PostgreSQL database cluster. **These are taken without affecting other clients to the database, and can be used both for point-in-time recovery** (see Section 25.3) and as the starting point for a log shipping or streaming replication standby servers (see Section 26.2).
>
> `pg_basebackup` makes a binary copy of the database cluster files, while making sure the system is put in and out of backup mode automatically. **Backups are always taken of the entire database cluster;** it is not possible to back up individual databases or database objects. **For individual database backups, a tool such as `pg_dump` must be used.**
>
> **The backup is made over a regular PostgreSQL connection, and uses the replication protocol. The connection must be made with a superuser or a user having REPLICATION permissions (see Section 21.2), and pg_hba.conf must explicitly permit the replication connection.** The server must also be configured with max_wal_senders set high enough to leave at least one session available for the backup and one for WAL streaming (if used).
>
> There can be multiple pg_basebackups running at the same time, but it is better from a performance point of view to take only one backup, and copy the result.
> ...

<sup>[pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgbasebackup.html) (PostgreSQL 12 Documentation</sup>

#### Taking a Base Backup

Once everything has been configured (read the whole documentation) you can then perform a base backup using the following command:

```
bash #> pg_basebackup -D \postgresql\backup\ -F t -R -z -h yourhost -p 5432 -U root -W
```

This can be used on an interactive bash prompt. When setting up a crontab job, you will have to create a `.pgpass` file. This will allow you to run the command as a
crontab job, without having to enter a password.

Please read [33.15. The Password File](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-pgpass.html) (PostgreSQL Documentation) for more details.

#### Constant WAL Archiving

The article [25.3. Continuous Archiving and Point-in-Time Recovery (PITR)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-BASE-BACKUP) contains information on how to archive the WAL (write ahead log) files that PostgreSQL creates. These files are required to restore a PostgreSQL cluster to a certain point-in-time.

> At all times, PostgreSQL maintains a write ahead log (WAL) in the pg_wal/ subdirectory of the cluster's data directory. **The log records every change made to the database's data files. This log exists primarily for crash-safety purposes: if the system crashes, the database can be restored to consistency by “replaying” the log entries made since the last checkpoint.** However, the existence of the log makes it possible to use a third strategy for backing up databases: **we can combine a file-system-level backup with backup of the WAL files.** If recovery is needed, we restore the file system backup and then replay from the backed-up WAL files to bring the system to a current state. **This approach is more complex to administer** than either of the previous approaches, but it has some significant benefits:
>
> - We do not need a perfectly consistent file system backup as the starting point. Any internal inconsistency in the backup will be corrected by log replay (this is not significantly different from what happens during crash recovery). So we do not need a file system snapshot capability, just tar or a similar archiving tool.
> - **Since we can combine an indefinitely long sequence of WAL files for replay, continuous backup can be achieved simply by continuing to archive the WAL files. This is particularly valuable for large databases, where it might not be convenient to take a full backup frequently.**
> - It is not necessary to replay the WAL entries all the way to the end. We could stop the replay at any point and have a consistent snapshot of the database as it was at that time. Thus, this technique supports point-in-time recovery: it is possible to restore the database to its state at any time since your base backup was taken.
> - If we continuously feed the series of WAL files to another machine that has been loaded with the same base backup file, we have a warm standby system: at any point we can bring up the second machine and it will have a nearly-current copy of the database.

You would then simply copy the contents of the `WAL` directory to a destination of your choice or backup those files and have a job that deletes old files after they haven been backed up to a safe location.

#### General Recommendation

Read the the section [Chapter 25. Backup and Restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/backup.html) from the official PostgreSQL documentation. If you are unable to understand how to implement a backup strategy, then please contact a consultant who can support you implementing a solution. There is nothing worse than not having a database backup when the proverbial "s.. hits the fan."

Having a base backup will have you partly covered. If you can run that on a daily basis, then you are half way there. But if this is not feasible, then you will at least have to set up the WAL archiving.

Comment: Thanks John @Johnkn. really appreciate it..